# mod_tile cache size limit

Tags: caching, openstreetmap, mapnik

I have a TMS server with apache mod_tile, mapnik & renderd. I have 400GB of free space on my cache folder.

I want to pre-render 11 or 12 levels.
I tried the command "render_list -a -z 0 -Z 10 -v -n 4".

But my cache folder doesn't grow more than 2.6GB and render_list says it finished, no error message.

Even when I use my map (openlayer) missing tiles are rendered on the fly but not stored in cache. Before I pre-rendered my tiles, they were stored in cache.

I searched unsuccessfully,so I ask here : Is there any option in Mod_tile to manage cache size and cache replacement strategy ?

Thanks for your answers.

udpdate : Strangely when I request tile from level 11, they are well stored in cache, and my cache grows. So is there a size limit per level ?

Comment: Did you get an answer?